# Is there any way to control the separation between columns in beamer? columns use a different with than the text below them

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43,t]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{columns}[T] 
\column{.49\textwidth}
\justifying
\lipsum[1-1][1-1]
\column{.49\textwidth}
\justifying
\lipsum[1-1][1-1]
\end{columns}
\justifying
\medskip
\lipsum[1-1][1-4]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `column` environment instead of the `\column` command and `\hfill` between two adjacent `column` environments. I also reduced the width of both columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43,t]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
  \begin{columns}[T] 
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
      \justifying
      \lipsum[1-1][1-1]
    \end{column}
    \hfill
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
      \justifying
      \lipsum[1-1][1-1]
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
  \justifying
  \medskip
  \lipsum[1-1][1-4]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, you can also use the `onlytextwidth` option of the `columns` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43,t]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
\begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth] 
  \column{.49\textwidth}
    \justifying
    \lipsum[1-1][1-1]
  \column{.49\textwidth}
    \justifying
    \lipsum[1-1][1-1]
\end{columns}
\justifying
\medskip
\lipsum[1-1][1-4]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```